# get European style week numbers

Tags: .net, sql-server-ce, date-formatting

Apparently SQL-CE 3.5 thinks of week numbers as if the whole world was American.
I do however live in the EU, in the Netherlands. What is the right SQL-CE function to retrieve, for example:

- The week number from any given date
- The previous week number start date
- Current week number start

IF SQL-CE is just unable to answer this in European week starts.
Then is there some kind of (prefereably free) code to convert in between dates, 
so we have a function that can translate between EU and American styles of week numbers?

So that if we enter a European time range, week 1 to week 3, it gets translated to day X and day Y.

Answer (score 1):

Do you mean ISO 8601 week numbers? If so, that is determined by the following rule: each week begins on Monday and is a part of the year containing that week's Thursday.

Effectively, that means that if 1 January falls on Monday, Tuesday, Wednesday or Thurdays, that week is week number 1 of the year. If 1 January falls on Friday, Saturday or Sunday, Then that week is week 53 of the previous year and week number #1 is the following week.

Sql Server 2008 and later provide direct support, using the built-in function `datepart(isowk,{some-date-time-value-here})`. This post, [ISO Week In SQL Server](http://blogs.lessthandot.com/index.php/DataMgmt/DataDesign/iso-week-in-sql-server), provides a  user-defined function for SQL Server 2005 and earlier.

Comment: Yes i mean iso 8601, but i'm not familiar with SQL-CE on how to retrieve things in those iso 8601 based time formats (SQL-CE doesnt understand them) so i was thinking if i can retrieve week number might it be possible to get pure dates for date-time-spannning functions